# How to detect overlay data in RTF files?

Tags: malware, tools, file-format, static-analysis

How to detect overlay data in RTF files? When officemalscanner says it detected overlay data, what does that mean ? Is overlay data specific to malicious files ?

Comment: I don't know answer for this but, I was developed a RTF parser for specific data set. You can also use context-specific expressions for your data.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say for sure since the tool is closed-source, but *I suspect* it means that the file contains extra data after the end of the document. For example, RTF usually begins with `{\rtf1`, contains many embedded commands  (some using nested `{}` for parameters) and ends with a matching `}`. If there is extra data after the final `}`, it's not part of the document but could be part of the payload used by the exploit inside the main body. It is of course not a 100% indicator of a malicious file but just one of the possible hints that it should be checked more thoroughly.

To confirm, you can try running it on this sample RTF file from Wikipedia:

```
{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard
This is some {\b bold} text.\par
}
```

Add some extra data at the end and see if it triggers the warning.

Comment: Good answer, “overlay” is a term from MSDOS days and used to mean exactly this. Malscan author is probably old :-)